# Shell script to compile C files

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I used to have a shell script that would compile all of the FILE.c files in a directory to FILE.out

I lost it and am trying to remake it and have the following which I know is very similar but can't tell where I am going wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in 'ls *.c'
do
    gcc -g3 -o3 $i -o {$i%.}.out
done
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a Makefile?

Comment: I don't understand makefiles.

Comment: You should take the time to learn makefiles. Honestly, they aren't actually that much more complicated than a shell script.

Comment: I should, but I'm so close with this script.

Comment: @sdadasd: Yes, you're very close to [reinventing the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel). Congratulations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to run the command `ls *.c`. Bash will expand the wildcard pattern for you automatically. So if you're completely desperate and do not want to make a Makefile you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in *.c
do
    echo "gcc -g3 -o3 $i -o ${i%.c}.out"
    # gcc -g3 -o3 "$i" -o "${i%.c}.out"
done
```

#### Example

Say I had this sample data:

```
$ ls -1
a.c
b.c
c.bash
c.c
d.c
e.c
```

Running my script `c.bash`:

```
$ ./c.bash 
gcc -g3 -o3 a.c -o a.out
gcc -g3 -o3 b.c -o b.out
gcc -g3 -o3 c.c -o c.out
gcc -g3 -o3 d.c -o d.out
gcc -g3 -o3 e.c -o e.out
```

To make the script run you'd comment out the `echo` line above, and uncomment the `gcc` line.

Answer (score 1):

Looking specifically at your question it appears that “where you went wrong” is in your parameter expansion. I think you were trying to change the value of i when naming the output file here:

```
{$i%.}
```

I think you misplaced the dollar sign. You may have meant:

```
${i%.}
```

Although honesty that would have only removed the “.” from the original file name. Whereas “filename.c” would have yielded “filenamec.out”. You probably want:

```
${i%.*}
```

This would have yielded “filename.out”. This parameter expansion syntax translates to a non-greedy deletion of everything starting at “.” and after. For greedy deletion the syntax would be:

```
${i%%.*}
```

I hope this answers your question better as it relates to your code.

Comment: This is mostly correct but `${i%.}` will actually remove nothing from `filename.c`.  It would only remove the `.` if the file actually ended with `.` like `filename.`

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop `for i in 'ls *.c'` is looping over the literal string "`ls *.c`", not the output command as you intended. This could be fixed by using the command substitution operator (e.g. `for i in $(ls *.c); do...`) but as slm points out [in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137069/72471) the command is not necessary at all as you can use the output of shell globbing in for-loop :)

This whole issue could also be solved more properly with a simple makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -Wall -Werror -g
RM = rm -f
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
PROGS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(PROGS)

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g3 -o3 -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(PROGS)
```

Save as "Makefile", run `make`. Remove compiled programs (clean) by running `make clean`. (Partially source by [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706067/3739455))

Comment: This answer would be _much_ better if it just gave the make file solution. That's a valuable contribution but the _faux pas_ at the top is holding this answer back. While you correctly identify the problem with the OP's use of a string, you've only replaced it with a completely un-necessary parsing of `ls` which is [generally not a good thing to do](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).